# How to exclude all but a particular file in gitignore?

Tags: git

I want git to track **libbsp.a** below, but not other .a files. 
How to modify my .gitignore file?

bond/arch/mips/src/bsp/libbsp.a
bond/arch/mips/src/libarch.a

My .gitignore file is in bond/ directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude all `.a` files, then unexclude the one you want.

```
*.a
!arch/mips/src/bsp/libbsp.a
```

Similar examples are shown in the docs [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: A nail on the head. Thanks. I tried to accept the answer immediately, but it seems there is time limit.